# objective-c runtime delegates question

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, delegates, uiwebview

So this may be a really dumb question, but is it possible to create a new delegate object at runtime without having to create an entire class interface/implementation for it?  I basically wanna spawn off a new webview and make a delegate for it that just implements webViewDidFinishLoad so I can do some size manipulation then.  It seems like a lot of overhead to create an entirely new class just for one method.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the delegate methods in your existing class. Just set the delegate to `self` and implement the methods you want.

Comment: Im already using that class as a delegate of a separate webview, and I want them to have different behaviors.  I have other classes that could implement the delegate protocol, but it just wouldnt make sense to do so

Comment: To differentiate `UIWebView`'s give each one a tag and use that to differentiate between views in the delegate methods.

Comment: You can set self as delegate to multiple webviews. The delegate method gets passed the webview object that it belongs to. So in the method you can decide what to do depending on which webview called it.